# Laravel 5.4 - Query relationship with search termn

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

i'm working in laravel 5.4, i have this tables:

**PROJECT**
| id | tags | title |

**PRODUCT**
| id | project_id | category_id |

**CATEGORY**
| id | name |

The tags of project is a string separated by comma:

> tag1,tag2,tag3...

The first step that i need is filter projects by termn:

```
$termn = 'examples';
$projects = Project::where('tags', 'LIKE' , '%'.$termn.'%')->paginate(20);
```

it work well, but i would like get all product's project with a specific "category_id".

My relations models is working well.

Thank you for your help! this is the first time that i'm trying to do something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) method:

```
Project::where('tags', 'like' , '%'.$termn.'%')
       ->with(['products' => function($q) use($categoryId) {
           $q->where('category_id', $categoryId);
       }])
       ->paginate(20);
```